# how to shift values to the next line in a txt file

Tags: python, numpy

I have a txt file with floats separated by blank space I need to to keep only 4 elements in each line. I tried to calculate blankspace. Now i need to shift the rest of the values to the next line and restart.

```
fname = open("file.txt", 'r') 
text = fname.read()
countBlank=0 
for line in text:
    for char in line:
        if char.isspace():
            countBlank += 1
        if countBlank ==4
```

Comment: We use `"\n"` to represent a new line

Answer (score 0):

Try this, works for me.

```py
floatlist = fname.read().split(" ")

count = 0
finalstring = ""
for x in floatlist:
    count += 1
    if count == 4:
        finalstring += x + "\n"
    else:
        finalstring += x + " "
```

Input:

```
"1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8"
```

Output:

```
"1 2 3 4
5 6 7 8"
```

How to write into file: (on the end of the existing code)

```py
fname.close()
fname = open("file.txt", "w")
fname.write(finalstring)
fname.close()
```

Comment: With Attitude, Thanks but how to save them in the file

Comment: @user77540 I've edited the code and put the updated script on the end.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by converting your data and storing it in an array then you can output it to a new file like this:

```
import numpy as np

fname = open("file.txt", 'r') 
text = fname.read()

arr = np.array(text.split())
rows = len(arr) // 4
remain = len(arr) % 4
out = np.full((rows+1, 4), None).astype(float)
out[:rows, :] = arr[:-remain]
out[rows, :remain] = arr[len(arr)-remain:]
np.savetxt('file2.txt', out)
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks but i got an error in  out[:rows, :] = arr[:-remain]

ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (0) into shape (2,4)

Comment: @user77540 seems to me like you have extra lines that are not in my code. Are you calling `read` multiple times? You should only do that once.

Comment: @user77540 So there are no other lines in your program? Are you running this in a terminal?

Comment: @user77540 please accept this answer if it solved your problem.